# Failed to load the "Vendor_ModuleName/payment/mypay-form" template requested by "checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.mypay"

Tags: checkout, uicomponent, payment

Magento 2.4.6-p2

When trying to add my custom payment I've got an error in console when going to checkout/#payment page. Something like that:

> [ERROR] Failed to load the "Alex_Mypay/payment/mypay-form" template
> requested by "checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.mypay"

Does anybody know where this bug is from?

Copy/paste from Magento_OfflinePayments

> app/code/Alex/Mypay/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/mypay-method.js

```
defaults: {
            template: 'Alex_Mypay/payment/mypay-form'
        },
```

And have a template in

> app/code/Alex/Mypay/view/frontend/web/template/payment/mypay-form.html

exact copy of

> vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html

And weird, I got something on my payments list anyway. I got the form but without a button correctly rendered, without a title (default or translated).

How it could render form and at the same time give me an error "Failed to load the template"? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my question, in case someone encounters the same issue.

Turned out, in app/code/Alex/Mypay/view/frontend/web/template/payment/mypay-form.html I had a variable that was missing in my method renderer app/code/Alex/Mypay/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/mypay-method.js

I left input with data-bind to 'purchaseOrderNumber' from Magento_OfflinePayments but removed it from renderer.

```
defaults: {
            template: 'Alex_Mypay/payment/mypay-form',
            purchaseOrderNumber: '' // this was missing
        },
```

In my case, I have removed 'purchaseOrderNumber' from my payment completely. From renderer and template.

For me, it was confusing and misleading to see such an error in console. Because it was a bug in template itself but not something wrong with loading the template :(

Hope this will help someone.